# How to catch Android application closing

Tags: java, android

I want to have a function that is called when my application is closed. All of my activities in my application extend a custom class `MenuActivity` which in turn extends the `Activity` class. In MenuActivity, I have the following code...

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    System.out.println("DESTROY IT");

}
```

For some reason, I never see this text. I've tried both with and without `super.onDestroy();` in there. I want this to be able to be called when the user closes the application (holds the home button to view the open applications and swipe to close), or if the application crashes. I need to do a bit of clean-up on application close (close ongoing notifications, and a few other things).

I thought it should be simple enough to use the onDestroy method, but it never seems to get called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

method `onDestroy()` won't be called every time, but you can do like this:

```
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause()
   if (isFinishing()) {
       //call some method
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this method too, and it doesn't seem to work. The code in the `if(isFinishing())` clause is never reached when you hold down the menu button and swipe the activity left or right to close it.

Comment: when you hold down the menu button your activity is not closing it either stops or pauses. your activity finishes when you press back button, or call method finish().

Comment: It is not called when you open your task manager and end the task from there either.

Comment: when you end the task from task manager, you app is being killed, and no methods will be called

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your application running when users are using other applications you need to implement your media player as a foreground service.  You can pass a notification when starting this service.

Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html especially the section on "Running as a foreground service"

Answer (score 0):

You should use onStop() for this.
You can read more about the android activity lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

The android developer guides are a great resource.

Comment: The `onStop()` method isn't sufficient for what I want. What I'm doing is creating an ongoing notification that allows you to play, pause, and go to the previous and next songs in my application. I want this notification to remain alive even if you switch to another application, or go home on your phone, so you can still access the player's functions outside of the app. The `onStop()` function is called if you hit home on your phone, so this defeats the purpose of my ongoing notification.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a Service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html